# Is there a noun corresponding to "to gather again"?

Tags: prepositions, word-request, nouns

I'm putting together a timetable for a day in London, and one of the slots is about people gathering again to go back home. Now I'm wondering how to say this (the ??? in the example below):

10.15 a.m. Arrival at Victoria station

10.30 a.m.–12 p.m Sightseeing tour by coach

12–1 p.m. Lunch

1–3 p.m. London Dungeon

3–8 p.m. Free time

8 p.m. ???

I would like to have a noun meaning 'to gather again', postmodified by "trip back home", for instance "Reassembly for the trip back home", but I'm not sure "reassembly" works, or whether the preposition ("for") is correct. I realise the postmodifier may seem unnecessary, but I would still like to know how to say it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, ***regroup*** is credible for the context, but it has strong connotations with *military* activities...

> **regroup** [<sup><sub>(Merriam-Webster)</sub></sup>](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regroup)
> intransitive verb
> 1: to reorganize (as after a setback) for renewed activity
> 2: to alter the tactical formation of a military force

So I suggest...

> **reconvene** = to **convene** again
> **convene**  [<sup><sub>(Merriam-Webster)</sub></sup>](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/convene)
> to come together in a body
> Example usage: *We convened at the hotel for a seminar.*

In M-W's example it's possible "we" never gathered together as a group before the seminar, but ***reconvened*** would imply we *were* together at least *once* before (which is obviously true of OP's day-trippers).

---

It's not really helpful for OP to ask for a ***noun*** to fit his context. Most native Anglophones would simply use my suggested ***verb*** to refer to the "activity" scheduled to happen at 8:00. The noun ***reconvention*** doesn't really work.

Comment: Thank you! So, just so I understand correctly, there is no way I could express this as a noun phrase in an idiomatic way? Not even if I used other words? It just seems really wrong to have a verb here, when all the other items on the agenda are noun phrases? But you're saying it'd be ok to just have "reconvene for the trip back home", even given the form of the previous items?

Comment: Perhaps I could have "Time to reconvene for the trip back home"? Or would that just sound forced? If there really is no way to phrase it as a noun phrase, would "Reconvening for the trip back home" be better than "Reconvene for the trip back home"?

Comment: There isn't really a "thing" to apply a noun to in your context anyway. Except insofar as it's an ***action*** (the "act" of performing the ***verb***). And it's pointless shifting the semantic goalposts to make "time" into the "head noun". Just use the verb.

Comment: No, that's true, but the same goes for the first item on the agenda – arrival, right?

Comment: Yes, but that one works fine with both ***Arrival*** and ***Arrive***. At the other end of the day, you can only really go for ***Reconvene at [location] for return journey***. As poinmte out ages ago, ***reconvention*** doesn't work here.

Comment: No, right – I totally get that "reconvention" doesn't work! I meant if there was some other way I could say it in the form of a noun phrase, since it seems so odd to have a verb all of a sudden, when all the other items are NPs. Anyway, so, you'd say "reconvene" is better that "reconvening"? And you'd say "Time to reconvene" would only sound forced?

Comment: Sorry! I see now that you've edited your previous comment so you've already answered these questions! Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: Perhaps in *your* native language (which I assume has nouns and verbs) it looks odd to switch between verbs and nouns for the "timed events / activities" in your example context. But Anglophones wouldn't notice anything like that. And verb-based ***arrive*** is [definitely more likely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=am+Arrival+at%2Cam+Arrive+at&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) for your first event.

Comment: Thank you so much again! This is really helpful! I have now changed to "arrive" :)

Answer (score 1):

The verb **to regroup** would work in this context. [As The Free Dictionary notes](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/regroup), this can mean:

> To come together again in a group.

Comment: Thank you! What would the noun for that be then? And what preposition do I use for the postmodifier?

Comment: @Gerda "A regroup" can mean [an act of regrouping, as Wiktionary says](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/regroup). But this use is rare; I would just use the imperative "Regroup for the trip back home," even though the other items on the schedule are nouns.